# running number begins from 1 every year

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'd wish to make a number that will start from 1 in the beginning of a brand new year, is it possible to do so?

When the user enters the date

It will save into two types (One is full date in the `date column`, the other is to take the year of the date and insert it into the `year` column of the `sf_table` Table)

HTML:

```
//Date
<div>
<label for="SDate">Insert Date</label></br>
<input type="date" id="sdate" name="SDate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>" required>
</div>


//Auto output the display of the running number (That will save into the database once the submit button is pressed)
<div>
<label for="Rno">Running Number</label></br>
<input type="text" name="Rno" id="runningno" readonly>
</div>
```

PHP: (When the submit button is pressed)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $year = //(get year from $date);

            $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['SDate']);
            $rnum = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Rno']);

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into sf_table (date,year,rnum) values (?,?,?)");
            $stmt -> bindParam(1,$date);
            $stmt -> bindParam(2,$year);
            $stmt -> bindParam(3,$rnum);


            $stmt -> execute();    
}
```

What Javascript functions and sql statements I should write and modify in my .php file to conduct this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not having experience in php as i am a java developer but I can help you with script

In Java script you need to
Convert the date to Date format by using

```
var date=new  Date(document.getElementById('sdate').value) var year=date.getFullYear(); var month =date.getMonth()+1; var dateOnly=date.getDate();
```

Hope it clarified your doubt